# Trying to read two tables that I have linked in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have this php below if the user submit my search form:

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
 $search = $_POST['search'];
 $readPosts = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE type= 'post' AND title LIKE ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
 $readPosts->bindValue(1, "%$search%");
 $readPosts->bindValue(2, $first, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $readPosts->bindValue(3, $max, PDO::PARAM_INT);

}
```

Then if the user dont submit the search form I have this:

```
else
{
 $readPosts = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE type= 'post' ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
 $readPosts->bindValue(1, $inicio, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $readPosts->bindValue(2, $maximo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
```

And then I execute my query and I´ll show the results in a table:

```
    $readPosts->execute();
     $resultReadPosts = $readPosts->rowCount();
     if(!$resultReadPosts >= 1)
     {
     echo 'there are no posts yet';
     }
     else
    {
    echo ' <table width="560" border="0" class="tbdados" style="float:left;"    cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Title:</td>
      <td align="center">Category:</td>
      <td align="center">Content:</td>
      <td align="center" colspan="3">Actions:</td>
    </tr>';
```

And now **cames the problem**:

I have a table for posts and one table for categorys, and until now I only read the posts table, and now I need to read the categorys table to search in my table the category of each post to show it, so Im trying like this:

```
 while ($resultReadPosts= $readPosts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {

  $readCat=  $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM categories WHERE id = ?");
  $readCat->bindValue(1,$resultReadPosts['id']);
  $readCat->execute();
  $resultReadCat = $readCat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $rowsCat = $lerCate->rowCount();
  print_r($rowsCat);

 echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>'.$resultReadPosts['titulo'].'</td>';  
     echo '<td align="center">'.$resultReadCat['name'].'</td>;
     echo '<td align="center">'.$resultReadPosts['content'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>Create</td>';
     echo '<td>Edit</td>';
     echo '<td>Delete</td>';  
  echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
```

Comment: are you getting any error? and you have syntax errors in your code 'no ending quote'--> `$resultReadCat['name'].'</td>;` and is it type or tipo `WHERE tipo = 'post' `

Comment: That was a error doing the translation here. Im not having any error! But When I do print_r($rowsCat) it shows 0 rows!

Comment: why you have given it like this `"%$search%"` try with normal `$search`

Comment: Thanks, its more correct like you said and I changed, but the problem is not there!

Comment: what are you getting here print it and check -->`$search = $_POST['search'];`

Comment: Nothing, because Im not using the search form, Im just trying to show my records in the table with category name!

Comment: So the $search is empty because I just use this variable When I use the search form!

Comment: if the $search is empty then how can the query will execute???

Comment: try to give some value manually to $search

Comment: If i give values to my search its working fine the search form!